# Ambari version tab not displaying anything

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am relatively new to Hadoop and have been trying to set up a development environment for a project I am involved with (CentOS 6.5 is the OS).  I originally set up the environment using Ambari 1.7 and installing the Hortonworks Data Platform version HDP-2.2.0.0-2041.

Now, I am trying to upgrade to Ambari 2.0.1 and HDP-2.2.6.0.

Ambari upgraded with no problems at all.  I also was able to register the new version of HDP through the Ambari Manage Version page.  That all went fine.

The problem is when I try to finish the upgrade.  The instructions say to go from the Admin menu to "Stack and Versions" then the "Versions" tab.  There, I am supposed to see my registered versions and a link to complete the upgrade.  However, all I get is a blank page.

FYI, I tried multiple browsers to rule out a browser issue.  I tried Firefox and Opera.  (I've heard that Chrome is no longer supported for CentOS so didn't try that).

Anyone know why this page would just be blank and/or how I can fix it?

Thanks!
Tom

BTW, I tried to post images, but I don't have enough reputation points so I can't.  You'll have to take my word for it that Manage Versions is showing the correct versions but the Versions tab under Stack and Versions is completely blank.

Answer (score 0):

Have you clicked on button on the picture? Ambari redirects me to Versions page automatically, when I am doing that:
[image: Ambari Versions page]